# Using Photos framework iOS to get metadata without retrieving the full image

Tags: ios, swift, photosframework

Is it possible to use the Photos framework in iOS to retrieve the metadata for every photo without loading the entire image into memory?

It is possible using imageIO, but I need the image URL. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1654/_index.html

But how can I get the URL without retrieving the images?